# How to launch Google Compute instances programmatically?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

In the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances can be launched programmatically via the [AmazonEC2Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html). Does [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/) in general or [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) specifically [just offer the CLI-based](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud) `gcloud` command for the equivalent operation? Or can GCE instances be controlled from Java/Python/Go/etc as well? Which SDK exists for those languages and where are the examples & docs for this?

I am looking for the equivalent of this in the GCP world:

```
client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
client.runInstances(new RunInstancesRequest())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [Google Cloud Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries), of which [`gcloud-java`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java) is the Java implementation. There are also Client Libraries in Go, Node.js, Python, and Ruby.

Under the covers everything in Google Cloud is available via an API, so even if there isn't a client library for what you're trying to accomplish, it can be done programmatically by calling the API directly.

The documentation on [launching instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance) has an API tab that shows both Client Library and REST API examples.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is still in alpha but it is available on Github: [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/tree/master/gcloud-java-compute). There is an example for starting GCE instances in the [java-docs-samples project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/compute/cmdline/src/main/java/ComputeEngineSample.java#L157).